# Alternative to HTML Parsing with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, node.js

I'm parsing HTML with regex in node.js to return a string.  However, I have been told that this is not a good idea in this post: [Pull a specific string from an HTTP request in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005274/pull-a-specific-string-from-an-http-request-in-node-js)

What are the more stable alternatives?

I'm new to programming, so links to tutorials would be very helpful. I have trouble understanding some of the documentation explanations.

Comment: You've already been informed of the issue but you should probably read [this](http://goo.gl/i8h6) just to be totally informed.  The basic issue has to do with the theoretical "power" of the "machine" model of regular expressions versus what's required to parse a language like HTML. It has to do with language/automata theory.

Comment: You can see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372972/how-do-i-parse-a-html-page-with-node-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[node-htmlparser](https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser) handles all of the heavy lifting of parsing HTML.  On top of that, [node-soupselect](https://github.com/harryf/node-soupselect) lets you use CSS-style selectors to find the particular element you're looking for.

**However**, I looked at your other question and the question you should really be asking is not "how do I scrape this data from a HTML page", but rather "is there a better way to retrieve the data I'm looking for?"  The USGS has [APIs that provide their data in machine-readable form](http://waterdata.usgs.gov/nwis/news/?automated_retrieval_info).

[Here's the JSON object for the location you're intersted in.](http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?sites=02334400&period=P7D&format=json)  To get the "most recent instantaneous value" for the elevation of reservoir surface, you'd download that file, do a `var d = JSON.parse`, and:

```
for (var i = 0; i < d.value.timeSeries.length; i++) {
    if (d.value.timeSeries[i].variable.variableName == 'Elevation of reservoir water surface above datum, ft') {
        var result = d.value.timeSeries[i].values[0].value[d.value.timeSeries[i].values[0].value.length-1];
    }
}
```

`result` will now look like `{ dateTime: "2012-04-07T17:15:00.000-05:00", value: "1065.91" }`.

Comment: Do I define `var d = JSON.parse` and the for statement in my `http.get` callback?

Comment: `http.get(..., function(res) { ... });` will call your callback when it makes a connection and *begins receiving data* -- not when it is complete.  You have to listen for data (`res.on('data', function(chunk) { ... });`) and buffer the incoming data, which you can then use to call `JSON.parse(bufferString)` once `res` emits `end`.  [See here for example.](http://nodemanual.org/latest/nodejs_dev_guide/creating_http_requests.html)